Html Razor - How to hide anchor link if specific div is not present
Currently I have an anchor div with three anchors present. But the #videos-anchor is showing even when we have no video present on the page.
<div class="anchor-bar__container">

                            <a href="#features-and-benefits-anchor">
                                <span class="anchor-bar__chevron"></span>
                                Features and Benefits
                            </a>
                             <a href="#videos-anchor">
                                <span class="anchor-bar__chevron"></span>
                                Videos
                            </a>
                            @if (Model.ProductSpecificationModel.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Attributes).ToList().Count > 0)
                            {
                                <a href="#product-specifications-anchor">
                                    <span class="anchor-bar__chevron"></span>
                                    Product Specifications
                                </a>
                            }
                            <a href="#related-products-anchor">
                                <span class="anchor-bar__chevron"></span>
                                Related Products
                            </a>
                        </div>

Essentially I would like to create in @if that would remove the video anchor link if no video is present. The name of the div that holds the videos is GNE-Overview-Video-Wrapper.
Any assistance on this would be much appreciated!
I am quite unfamilar with razor and would like some insite on the best approach to this issue.
